Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на картинку она затемнялась и появлялся кликабельный текст
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
 <style>

.container:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

  header {
  background-color: #949eb3;
}

.main{
background-color: #b1b8c7;
}

footer {
  background-color: #949eb3;

}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
   position: relative;
   top: -50px;
   right: -50px;
}
nav {
  float: right;
}
nav ul {
  position: relative;
  left: -200px;
  bottom: -11px;

}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px;
}

nav a {
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 30px;

}



h2 {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  position: relative;
  right: -260px;
  bottom: -39px;
}

.block div {
  float: right;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.block div {
  width: 50%;
 
}




</style>

</head>

<body>

<header>
 <div class="container-head">
     <h2 align="center">Апарт-отель <font color= "#edeff2">Ascella</font><br>Современный отель - не <font color= "#edeff2">сказка</font><br></h2>

  <a herf="/" class="logo">
     <img src="img/logo.png">
  </a>

 <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Number.html"><font color= "#000000">Номера</font></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><font color= "#000000">Услуги</font></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><font color= "#000000">Контакты</font></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><font color= "#000000">Бронирование</font></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><font color= "#000000">Спецпредложения</font></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
 </div>
</header>

<div class="main">
 <div class="block">
    <div class="col-1-2"><img src="img/room21.jpg" style="width:80%"></div>
    <div class="col-1-2"><img src="img/room22.jpg" style="width:80%"></div>    
    <div class="col-1-2"><img src="img/room24.jpg" style="width:80%"></div>
    <div class="col-1-2"><img src="img/room25.jpg" style="width:80%"></div>
    <div class="col-1-2"><img src="img/room26.jpg" style="width:80%"></div>
    <div class="col-1-2"><img src="img/room27.jpg" style="width:80%"></div>
 </div>
</div>

<footer>
 <div class="container">
  <h4><font color= "bfbfbf">2024 © Все права защищены</font></h4>
 </div>
</footer>


.kartinka:hover { filter: brightness(0.8); }

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

"кликабельный текст, или что то типо того" - кликабельный текст что? ссылка? кнопка?

@eccs0103 что бы при затемнение вылезал текст на который можно нажать и он бы переносил на другую страницу

Решение
Вот так к примеру.


/* Main part ↓ */

img.image:hover,
div.container:has(a.text:hover) img.image {
  filter: brightness(0.8);
  transition: 0.4s;
}

img.image:not(:hover)+a.text:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


/* Only for demo ↓ */

body {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
}

div.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img.image {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
}

a.text {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
}
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="https://i.sstatic.net/9Qeqa1fK.jpg">
  <a class="text" href="">Nice code, bro!</a>
</div>




большое спасибо!

а как выровнять Image что бы они были в таком порядке?
[  ]   [  ]
[  ]   [  ]
[  ]   [  ]

@TeterisFake это уже другой вопрос. Задайте его. Но для начала советую искать в интернете grid-template, довольно легкий вопрос.
